# Delete an entity with two OneToOne relations

Tags: symfony, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have a probleme for a job in Symfony 4.2.

I'm a beginner on Symfony and I need help for understand cascade deletion, and what I have a foreign key error

I have 3 entity like this :

The first is call Image

```
class Image
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(
    *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Thumbnail",
    *     mappedBy="Image",
    *     cascade={"persist"},
    *     orphanRemoval=true
    * )
    */
    private $Thumbnail;
}
```

the second is the Thumbnail of this image :

```
class Thumbnail
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(
    *     targetEntity="App\Entity\Image",
    *     inversedBy="Thumbnail",
    *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}
    * )
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    */
    private $image;
}
```

and a Div which contain a Thumbnail :

```
class Div
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Thumbnail", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
    private $Thumbnail;
}
```

this is my three entities, and my problem  is when I try to delete one of this three entities because :

- When I delete an Image I need to delete his Thumbnail, but the Div can live without Thumbnail so I mustn't delete the Div.
- When I delete a Thumbnail, I mustn't delete the Image, and I mustn't delete the Div
- When I delete the Div I mustn't delete the Thumbnail.

I would like to know the best practice for do this job.

Thank for help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your Div entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Thumbnail", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="thumbnail_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
*/
private $Thumbnail;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, this resolve my problem.

I just add the "ORM\@JoinColumn" line because for my project add Div Entity in my Thumbnail make no sense.

Comment: Please add my answer to correct for other user can easily find correct answer.